# URL retrieved from Google Digital Asset Links are unintentionally terminated with a period

Tags: google-api, firebase-hosting

## Overview

I am using Firebase and Google Asset links to use AppLinks in my Android app.
I uploaded to `https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json` with Firebase Hosting,
For some reason, the URL setting for `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls` has a period at the end.
Example: `https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app.`

`https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app` will not redirect, you have to send a request with `https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app.`

## Steps to Reproduce

Using Firebase Hosting, write `firebase.json`, `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` as follows

firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": "." ,.
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/. *", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type", 
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }, }
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type", 
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ], }
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
```

/.well-known/assetlinks.json

```
[
  {
      "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "android_app_name",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
              "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          ]
      }
  },
  {
      "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "android_app_name.dev",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
              "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          ]
      }
  },
  {
      "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "android_app_name.stg",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
              "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          ]
      }
  }
]
```

After Hosting, Use `curl --request GET 'https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json'`.

result

```json
[
  {
      "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "android_app_name",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
              "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          ]
      }
  },
  {
      "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "android_app_name.dev",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
              "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          ]
      }
  },
  {
      "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "android_app_name.stg",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
              "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          ]
      }
  }
]
```

`https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator?hl=ja` のサイトで確認する。

`Hosting サイトドメイン`
YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app

`アプリのパッケージ名`

1. android_app_name
2. android_app_name.dev
3. android_app_name.stg

`アプリ パッケージのフィンガープリント( SHA256 )`
"sha256_cert_fingerprints"

結果

```
1. Success! Host YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app grants app deep linking to android_app_name.
2. Success! Host YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app grants app deep linking to android_app_name.dev.
3. Success! Host YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app grants app deep linking to android_app_name.stg.
```

Test with `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`

result

```json
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "source": {
        "web": {
          "site": "https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app."
        }
      },
      "relation": "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "target": {
        "androidApp": {
          "packageName": "android_app_name",
          "certificate": {
            "sha256Fingerprint": "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "web": {
          "site": "https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app."
        }
      },
      "relation": "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "target": {
        "androidApp": {
          "packageName": "android_app_name.dev",
          "certificate": {
            "sha256Fingerprint": "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "web": {
          "site": "https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app."
        }
      },
      "relation": "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "target": {
        "androidApp": {
          "packageName": "android_app_name.stg",
          "certificate": {
            "sha256Fingerprint": "sha256_cert_fingerprints"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "maxAge": "998.121288586s"
}
```

Add the following settings to AndroidManifest.xml (Fails because host is different)

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="android_app_name">

  <!-- ~略~ -->
  <application
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name="${applicationName}"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
      <activity
          <!-- ~ -->
          >
          <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
              <!-- ↓ add App Links ↓ -->
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/custom_scheme" />
              <data android:scheme="http" android:host="YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app" />
              <data android:scheme="https" android:host="YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app" />
              <!-- ↑ add App Links ↑ -->
```

After building the actual machine in release mode,
In the terminal, use the command `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app"` 
App Links failed.

Rewrite AndroidManifest.xml as follows to succeed

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="android_app_name">

  <!-- ~略~ -->
  <application
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name="${applicationName}"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
      <activity
          <!-- ~略~ -->
          >
          <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <!-- ↓ add App Links ↓ -->
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/custom_scheme" />
              <!-- YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app. ← ADD A PERIOD AT THE END -->
              <data android:scheme="http" android:host="YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app." />
              <data android:scheme="https" android:host="YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app." />
              <!-- ↑ add App Links ↑ -->
```

After building the actual machine in release mode,
In the terminal, use the command `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app."` 
App links Success!

## What we tried

- Change hosting settings in firebase.json to "cleanUrls": true, false
- Change hosting setting in firebase.json to "trailingSlash": false
- Change "appAssociation" in firebase.json to "AUTO", "NONE
- Use cloud functions and rewrites to specify URL and files to retrieve

`functions/src/index.ts`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const redirectAssetLinks = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.redirect('https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json');
});
```

Add code to `firebase.json`

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    // ...
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "function": "redirectAssetLinks"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- Change `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` to public folder. Change `"source": "."` to `"public": "public"` in the hosting setting in firebase.json

#### Everything we have tried has not been effective

## Expected behavior

`https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://YOUR_HOSTING_URL_HERE.web.app&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls` retrieved in the link does not have a period App links succeed with the URL retrieved.